# Connect sensor via CAN BUS to PC

Tags: sensor, can

I need to read and process on PC (preferable in Python) the incline data from the CAN BUS inclinometer. The .pdf file with data sheet and a little messy protocol description: https://fastupload.io/HwXkd1kvguRJx8r/file

Can I use the ESP32? With what CAN transceiver? Better to decode the data on ESP32 or forward the data to PC and decode it there in Python?

Or maybe better and faster to implement is to buy something like this:
https://www.waveshare.com/product/usb-can-a.htm
or higher model:
https://www.waveshare.com/product/usb-can-b.htm

I am totally new to CAN and everything is very messy for me. Thanks for any suggestions, how to make this sensor to work.

I need to send the .pdf datasheet via hosting, because it is only available on request from manufacturer. If you know better way to share it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I use the ESP32?

Yes, you can.

2. With what CAN transceiver?

Pretty much anyone that works with 3.3V interface.

3. Better to decode the data on ESP32 or forward the data to PC and decode it there in Python?

Depends on what you want to do, either way would probably work. One extra layer adds to complexity, though.

4. Or maybe better and faster to implement is to buy something like this: (USB-CAN)

Same as above, depends on what you want to do. If all you need is to have the sensor data available in the PC software, this is likely the simplest way to go, where you only need to write one single software instead of adding an extra layer in form of the ESP32.

Comment: Do you think that both waveshare modules will work just fine, without any problems?